# Event Propagation-Related: Different events for parent (focusout) and child (click) both are trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p>Click the buttons to show and/or close the dialog window.</p>

    <button onclick="showDialog()">Show dialog</button>


    <p><b>Note:</b> The dialog element is only supported in Chrome 37+, Safari 6+ and Opera 24+.</p>

    <div tabindex=-1 id="myDialog" style="display:none">
        <div id="btn">Close dialog</div>
    </div>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myDialog");
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', closeDialog);
    x.addEventListener("blur", closeDialog);

    function showDialog() {
        x.style.display = "flex";
        x.focus();
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        x.style.display = "none";
        console.log("clicked");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the above code that triggers both event listeners, but when I change the inner div to `id='btn'` to button id ='btn' only one event is triggered but when I clicked on button, but when I clicked inner div both events are triggered. I don't know why. Any help, as I need to learn what is causing this.

only in chrome

Added code Pen Link Below:

https://codepen.io/arshan25/pen/MWJVpEV

Comment: I tried changing `<div id="btn">Close dialog</div>` to `<button id="btn">Close dialog</button>` and got the same result

Comment: For both cases got same result? for me it's different

Comment: Hi, have a check that you don't have a space after the id which you do have in your text.